# Retrieving date from a datetime column in python/django

Tags: python

I have a column in my database which is named date... in this column i am storing a datetime value...now when i want to filter the table according to date value(only date and not datetime)..say i want to retrieve all coloums having a particular date..then how can i apply such filtering(i.e getting date out of datetime column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, to match March 18, 2011:

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(date__year=2011, date__month=3, date__day=18)
```

Django docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#year

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(date__gte=date, date__lt=date+datetime.timedelta(1))
```

Not sure which is faster, this or dappawit's solution.